# FlutterError (A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderRepaintBoundary

Tags: flutter

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderRepaintBoundary.
RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.

The RenderViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by:
  Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#4d030] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#5be01] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#c19df] ← NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification> ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← ⋯

The RenderRepaintBoundary that did not match the expected child type was created by:
  RepaintBoundary ← NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> ← GlowingOverscrollIndicator ← Scrollable ← CustomScrollView ← Viewport ←
```

The above error is given by below code.I have written customScrollView inside another customScrollview.The second customScrollView is giving the error.Whenever i write without second customscrollview the code executed,but with second customscrollview the error is occured.I have tried with and without  RepaintBoundary,sliverToBoxAdapter,but again again same error occur

code:

```
CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            bottom: PreferredSize(preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(48),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              height: 80,
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                controller: _controller,
                tabs:  [
                  Tab( 
                    child: tab(text: "tab1",conIn:_controller.index,index:0)
                  ,),
                   Tab(child: tab(text: "tab2",conIn:_controller.index,index:1)
                  ,),
                   Tab(child: tab(text: "tab3",conIn:_controller.index,index:2)
                  ,),
                   
                  
              ]),
            ),),
        ),
     CustomScrollView(
    
  slivers: [
    TabBarView(
      controller: _controller,
      children: [
        RepaintBoundary(
          child: SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Text("");
              },
              childCount: 4,
            ),
          ),
        ),
         RepaintBoundary(
          child: SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Text("");
              },
              childCount: 4,
            ),
          ),
        ),
          RepaintBoundary(
          child: SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Text("");
              },
              childCount: 4,
            ),
          ),
        ),
       
      ],
    ),
  ],
),




        ],
      ),
```

App structure is:

- scaffold
- customScrollView
- sliverAppBar
- SliverToBoxAdapter
- Container
- TabbarView
- RepaintBoundary
- SliverList

List item

Comment: I am thinking do we need two customScrolView

Comment: i have tried with single also,but...

Comment: can you provide the exact widget structure you need , also if you can include error-produce snippet I can give a try

Comment: i have provided app structure

Comment: is it ok I fit all last widget on single CustomScrolView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ListView.builder with repaintBoundary

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          floating: true,
          pinned: true,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          elevation: 0,
          // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(80),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              height: 80,
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                controller: _controller,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text("a"),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text("a"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _controller,
            children: [
              RepaintBoundary(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text("$index");
                  },
                  itemCount: 4,
                ),
              ),
              RepaintBoundary(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text("$index");
                  },
                  itemCount: 4,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `slivers` accepts widgets from the `Sliver` widgets family, such as `SliverList`, `SliverPadding`..., but you're adding directly a non-silver's, even if it contains inside of it a sliver one, you need to expose a sliver directly in `slivers`.

There is a `SliverToBoxAdapter()` that adapts any Flutter widget to be used inside as a sliver, just wrap the `RepaintBoundary` with it like this:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: RepaintBounder(
   // ...
 ),
),
```

Comment: not working....